# Extra space below img link. Vertical align, line-height:0 do not fix.

Tags: image, alignment

Trying to align an `img` in a `div` bottom left of the container... except a magical space is appearing! I search around for an answer to this only to find `display:block` and `line-height:0`... but they don't work! Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

   <div id="block">
       <a href="home.html"><img src="Thumbs/coffeecup.JPG" width="95" height="80"
        alt="COFFEE CUP JPG" title="" /></a>

   </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {width:500px;
            height:500px;
            border:solid 1px;
            border-color:#000000;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position:relative; }

#block {width:100px;
        height: 100px;
        border:solid 1px;
        border-color:#000000;
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        }

img {vertical-align:bottom;
     display:block; 
     line-height:0;
     }
```

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Slimbruddah/rRAfF/)

I've tried all the other post examples. Not sure what's up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `div` has `width 100px` and `height 100px`, but your image's height is `80px` and width is `95px` only. Hence the white space. Just delete the property `width:100px` and `height:100px` of `#block`, white space will disappear.

Comment: Champion. Way too simple, my newbie eye's just missed it! Thanks man.